# Cron does not launch automatically

Tags: python, django, cron

My cron on my django project does not work. I mean I have to launch it manually using the following instruction :

`python3 manage.py crontab run 1a909d1e0a17391270108c0591b73ed`

I tried this : 
`python3 manage.py crontab add`

But it does not work automatically unfortunately ...

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this guide, it might help you fix the issue: https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/